# Why are jQuery set attributes not reflected in .html()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to set some attributes on HTML snippets. The purpose is to repopulate a form with previous inputed values. I set attributes with .attr() but after I do a .html(), I do not see my changed attributes.

I have done a basic example here http://jsfiddle.net/ejanderson4/CSYnU/

My function looks like this:

```
function setValue(html,value,name){
    var element=$(html);
    $(element).find("[name='"+name+"']").attr('value',value)
    return element.html();
}
```

Comment: are you trying to set the value or just trying to retrieve it

Comment: It sets it, but .html() doesn't return the html with the changed values, see http://jsfiddle.net/hRKs6/

Comment: Do you need the result as HTML? If you are going to use it in the page, you can just return the elements as elements instead of turning them into HTML and then back into elements. (See the edit in my answer below.)

Answer (score 1):

It is setting it, but for reasons unknown to me, you can't directly query the value attribute of an input element. You need to call `.val()` on that element to get it.

Updated your example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CSYnU/1/)

Answer (score 0):

parse the html string using `$.parseXML` and then set the attr value

```
var html="<div><label id='el_c5c0f78656138c39c5eb91a9bf1d3bf6'> table input 1 </label><input type='text' value='' name='table_input_1' class='select-mini' id='table_input_1' /></div>";

var value= 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx';

var name='table_input_1';

    function setValue(html,value,name){

        var xml = html,
        xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
        $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
        $title = $xml.find( "[name='"+name+"']" );
    $title.attr("value",value);
        //var element=$(html);
        //element.find("[name='"+name+"']").attr('value',value)

        return $title.attr("value");
    }

    alert(setValue(html,value,name));
```

here is the working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/CSYnU/4/

also this solution requires you to use jquery version 1.5.2 and higher

**update**

sry for overdoing it in your scenario you have to do

```
function setValue(html,value,name){
    var element=$(html);
    $(element).find("[name='"+name+"']").attr('value',value);

    return $(element).find("[name='"+name+"']").attr('value');
}
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/CSYnU/5/

you are wrapping the `html` in `$(html)` then there is no need to again wrap the cached `html` in `$`

```
var element = $(html);
element.find ...
```

see here http://jsfiddle.net/CSYnU/6/

Comment: No, it's not because the element is not part of the DOM, it works just fine to change other attributes, like the `id` for example. It's because the `value` property changes the current value, not the initial value.

Comment: Regarding the update... why not just `function setValue(value) { return value; }`? That would do the same...

Comment: html and name doesnt need to be passed explicitly as params as they are defined globally they can be accessed in-side the function...

Comment: You are missing the point completely. Why would you put the value in an element only read it back out from the element?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the current value of an input element doesn't change the initial value, which is what the `value` attribute is.

There is no property to change the initial value, so you can't alter the HTML code that way.

#### Edit:

If you want to use the elements in the page, then just make the function return a jQuery object containing the elements instead of returning HTML code:

```
function setValue(html, value, name){
  var elements = $(html);
  elements.find("[name='"+name+"']").val(value)
  return elements;
}
```

Adding the elements to the page works the same as using a string. Example:

```
var html = '<div><input type="text" name="city" /></div>';
$('#SomeForm').append(setValue(html, 'York', 'city'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Depend on your code, the first problem is about element variable. It doesn't denote "table_input_1" element. To get this element, you should replace by :

```
var element=$(html).find("[name='"+name+"']");
```

The second problem is in the your return statement. Since you changed the value of input element, you have to get this value by method val() or attr('value') rather than html(). The html() method is used to get the content inside tags of a element, but in this case value is a attribute, not content.

```
return element.attr('value'); // element.val();
```

Here is the complete code:

```
function setValue(html,value,name){
    var element=$(html).find("[name='"+name+"']");
    element.attr('value',value); // element.val(value);
    return element.attr('value'); // element.val();
}
```

Comment: I believe that the point is to produce HTML code, not return the value. The code `function setValue(value) { return value; }` would do the same as your suggested code, so that's pretty pointless...

Comment: I think he doesn't want to produce HTML code. In his post, he only want see his change, and the change he want to see is that the value of "table_input_1" element. You will see his purpose through values that he set in two variables : value and name. Here is his code:

    var value= 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    var name='table_input_1';

Answer (score 0):

I think the short answer here is that setting an attribute on a DOM object does not necessarily change what the browser returns for innerHTML.  If you want to retrieve a particular attribute, then you should just retrieve that attribute directly.

You also have an error in your code (which jQuery might be tolerating).  You've already turned element into a jQuery object so you don't need to do that again with $(element).find, you can just use element.find.

```
function setValue(html,value,name){
    var element=$(html);
    element.find("[name='"+name+"']").attr('value',value)
    return element.html();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One reason is that the jQuery *attr* method gets confused between HTML attributes and DOM properties. The imlpementation of *setAttribute* and *getAttribute* was (probably still is) buggy in IE, so in general forget about HTML attributes and use DOM properties.

In most browsers, modifying the HTML attribute (say using *setAttribute*) will modify the related DOM property. But in many browsers, changing the DOM property will not modify the HTML attribute.

Further, some browsers will modify an element's innerHTML based on the current DOM property, others will use the HTML attribute (which might have a different value in most browsers). HTML 5 is the first attempt to standardise the behaviour of innerHTML, note that it is not a W3C standard yet and is not consistently implemented.

The best approach is to be consistent and always set DOM properties to the values you want. Expect that an element's innerHTML may be inconsistent across browsers.